# Unable to load url in webview - black screen

Tags: java, android, url, android-webview

I have been trying a couple of approaches, some found here, to load a url with webview in my app, all so far unsuccessful with one particular page from a client. Let's for example take this approach:

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/background">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/top_heading"
        android:id="@+id/rlayout1">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="More Information" android:id="@+id/txtviewfbdisplaytitle" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@+id/rlayout1"
        android:id="@+id/rlayout2">
        <WebView android:id="@+id/webview1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
          @Override
          public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
              view.loadUrl(url);
              return true;
          }
    }
    Button btnBack;
    WebView webview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        openURL();
    }

     /** Opens the URL in a browser */
    private void openURL() {
        webview.loadUrl("[see solution]");
        webview.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

While other websites work, this one won't. I am fairly new to Android programming. What could I try next?

Side question: What does the url do differently to prevent a successful load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website uses DOM Storage to function and since by default DOM storage is disabled in `android webview` you have to enable it.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
openURL();
```